# ImageBackground won't appear

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to render a background image, and it runs, but nothing appears. I'm running this through Android on Windows. This is the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

import { View, Image, Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

```
class Background extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={{uri: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/purple-blue-textured-background-wallpaper-app-background-layout-dark-gradient-colors-vintage-distressed-elegant-78118630.jpg'}}
        style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}

      >
        <View >
          <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
  }
```

export default Background;

I'm not sure if the code just isn't properly pulling the image itself or if the styling needs to be adjusted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I may be wrong, but I guess you are missing ```height: '100%'```. in your ```ImageBackground``` component. Can you check it, please?

Answer (score 15):

Your ImageBackground component needs a height value in your style attribute. RN is picky about that.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't realize it was that picky, it now properly appears.

Answer (score 4):

```
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native'

<ImageBackground
source={require('../assets/background.jpg')}
resizeMode={'cover'}
style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}></ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality answers on Stack Overflow. This answer could be improved with an explanation as to how this solves OP's problem presented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

for me only shows when i use

```
require()
```

like this post
[ImageBackground not working when i call source from state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472862/imagebackground-not-working-when-i-call-source-from-state)

```
source={require( 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/purple-blue-textured-background-wallpaper-app-background-layout-dark-gradient-colors-vintage-distressed-elegant-78118630.jpg')}
```

(i tried to import image and call inside source but don't appears, even declaring in style height and width, only after use require(), why? i don't know)

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your ImageBackground component within a Container component.

```
class Background extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
      <Container>
        <ImageBackground
        source={{uri: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/purple-blue-textured-background-wallpaper-app-background-layout-dark-gradient-colors-vintage-distressed-elegant-78118630.jpg'}}
        style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}>
         <View >
           <Text>Test</Text>
         </View>
       </ImageBackground>
      </Container>
        );
    }
  }
```