# ImageBackground not working when i call source from state

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, imagebackground

ImageBackground does not show the image when I called source from state.

I tried to use a conditional statement like at first touchable opacity but not working again.

```
state = {
    color1: "../images/yellow-orb.png",
    color2: "../images/yellow-orb.png",
}
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.questSelect(1)}>
          {this.state.color1 ? (
            <ImageBackground
              source={{ uri: this.state.color1 }}
              style={styles.icon2}
            >
              <Text>1</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
          ) : (
            null
          )}
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.questSelect(2)}>
          <ImageBackground
            source={{ uri: this.state.color2 }}
            style={styles.icon2}
          >
            <Text>2</Text>
          </ImageBackground>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

At emulator, I can see texts like 1 2 3 .. but there aren't images.

Comment: Can you share the styles of your ImageBackground?

Comment: icon2: {
    height: Dimensions.get("window").width / 9,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 9,
    marginTop: Dimensions.get("window").width / 60
  },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `require()` in order to load from source.

eg:

```
 <ImageBackground
              source={require("../images/yellow-orb.png")}
              style={styles.icon2}
            >
              <Text>1</Text>
 </ImageBackground>
```

OR

update your state like this,

```
this.state = {
    color1: require("../images/yellow-orb.png"),
    color2: require("../images/yellow-orb.png"),
}
```

and use state value directly,

```
 <ImageBackground
              source={this.state.color1}
              style={styles.icon2}
            >
```

please check

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer, it will help the community to improve